# Custom command for an ember-cli app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

As I can't find anything in the docs:
is there a way to define custom (possibly application local) ember commands?

My goal is to create a command that starts a server for API stubs and then run tests (testem) in CI mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a new command for `ember-cli` by using an addon. In your addon's `index.js`, use `includedCommands` hooks. Visit the [docs](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_includedCommands) for more information. Also you can have a look at [ember-cli-commands](https://github.com/seawatts/ember-cli-commands) addons that register some commands.

By the way, for your tests, you should use [ember-cli-mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/). So you don't need to start another command or mock API.